# Writing your own FrontPage RPC server (like SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, webdav, frontpage

Does anybody have experience in programming a protocol handler (server) that talks FrontPage RPC? I want to make a server that behaves itself as if it was SharePoint.

What I want is to open a Word document from this Web Server, edit it in MS Word and write the changes to the Web server. So in the same way you can edit Word documents from SharePoint.

I tried using WebDAV, but the implementation of WebDAV in Microsoft Office is not working as good as FP-RPC.

Microsoft is telling the world to forget FrontPage RPC and to use WebDAV or CIFS but the latest versions of SharePoint and Office are still talking FrontPage RPC...

Comment: This thread has some answers for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792960/editing-ms-office-documents-from-a-web-application-custom-webdav-implementation

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java, there is nice [WebDAV Library](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html) in [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) project. I've used it extensively this year, and succeeded to implement webdav server on top of our existing storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to your question would be: yes, some people have experience doing this :)

A good place to start is http://www.webdav.org/